# How do I make Maps (Key / Value) in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

Looking to create a Image with a kind of Map with key/value in LaTeX like the one below:

[image]

I tried to make the image with TikZ and I got to the following script:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
  block/.style = {draw, minimum width=1.0cm, minimum height=0.7cm, node distance=3cm},
  down/.style={yshift=-4em}
}

\node[block] (4) at (0,0) {4};
\node[block,right of=4] (3) {3};
\node[block,right of=3] (7) {7};

\node[block] (A1) at ([down] 4) {A1};
\node[block] (A3) at ([down] 3) {A3};
\node[block] (A4) at ([down] 7) {A4};

\draw[->] (4) -- (3);
\draw[->] (3) -- (7);

\draw[->] (4) -- (A1);
\draw[->] (3) -- (A3);
\draw[->] (7) -- (A4);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

but how can I modify the lower nodes (A1, A3, A4) to make them look like tables?

Comment: You might look at the tikz package: http://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/~hellmund/LaTeX/pgf-tut.pdf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look at expl3 and its l3prop.

Comment: Just to clarify: Do want to implement such a key/value thing in latex or do you want to draw such an image? How is the tag `tableofcontents` involved in this? And why `tables`? Please give us a bit more context.

Comment: Hi everyone, I want to represent an image of a C++ maps, which is defined (map <K, V>) or (map <int, Info>), so for each key there is a value that would be my info (info) a series of parameters, eg K = 4, then V = {order with size 5, main with size 4 and net with size 3}.

Comment: Please give us complete code for the minimal document which reproduces the image. An obvious completion won't produce that image.

Comment: You can just put tabulars in the nodes in place of `A1` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have solved it using TikZ, attached scripts, thank you all.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, line width=0.25mm, minimum width=1.0cm, minimum height=0.7cm, node distance=3cm]
\tikzstyle{down} = [yshift=-4em]


\node[block, rounded corners] (4) at (0,0) {4};
\node[block,right of=4, rounded corners] (3) {3};
\node[block,right of=3, rounded corners] (7) {7};

\node[block] (A1) at ([down] 4) 
{ 
\begin{tabular}{ l   }
    order 5  \\ \hline
    main 4  \\ \hline
    net 3  \\
  \end{tabular} 
};
\node[block] (A3) at ([down] 3) 
{
\begin{tabular}{ l   }
    order 7  \\ \hline
    main 4  \\ \hline
    net 1 \\
  \end{tabular} 
};
\node[block] (A4) at ([down] 7) 
{
    \begin{tabular}{ l   }
    order 8  \\ \hline
    main 9  \\ \hline
    net 7  \\
  \end{tabular} 
};

\draw[->] (4) -- (3);
\draw[->] (3) -- (7);

\draw[->] (4) -- (A1);
\draw[->] (3) -- (A3);
\draw[->] (7) -- (A4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Maps} \label{fig:M1}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a `tikz matrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{
            block/.style = {draw, minimum width=1.0cm, minimum height=0.7cm, rounded corners, node distance=3cm},
            mymatrix/.style = {matrix of nodes, nodes={draw, text width=4em, minimum height=4ex, inner xsep=6pt}, 
                row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, inner sep=0pt},
        }
        \node[block] (4) at (0,0) {4};
        \node[block,right= of 4] (3) {3};
        \node[block,right= of 3] (7) {7};
        \matrix[mymatrix, below= of 4] (A1) {%
            order 5\\
            main 4\\
            net 3\\
        };
        \matrix[mymatrix, below= of 3] (A3) {%
            order 7 \\ 
            main 4 \\ 
            net 1 \\
        };
        \matrix[mymatrix, below= of 7] (A4) {%
            order 8  \\ 
            main 9  \\ 
            net 7  \\
        };
        \draw[->] (4) -- (3);
        \draw[->] (3) -- (7);
        \draw[->] (4) -- (A1);
        \draw[->] (3) -- (A3);
        \draw[->] (7) -- (A4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Maps\label{fig:M1}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The whole picture can be defined in only one `matrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{
            block/.style = {draw, text width=2em, minimum height=0.7cm, rounded corners, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center, align=center},
            register/.style = {draw, text width=4em, minimum height=4ex, inner xsep=6pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center}, 
            map/.style={matrix of nodes, nodes=register, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=1cm, row 1/.style={nodes=block}},
        }
        \matrix[map] (A) {
            4 & 3 & 7 \\[1cm]
         order 5 & order 7 & order 8\\
         main 4 & main 4 & main 9\\
         net 3 & net 1& net 7\\
        };
          \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
                \draw[->] (A-1-\i) -- (A-2-\i);
        \draw[->] (A-1-1) -- (A-1-2);
        \draw[->] (A-1-2) -- (A-1-3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Maps\label{fig:M1}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]